# SQL Server QUERY + UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a pretty hard procedure to make, maybe you can help me? I know there are very good programmers around here...

```
USE [MuOnline]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[LiveMu_Transfer cashpoint to gem]  Script Date: 01/05/2015 01:29:03 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
    BEGIN 
    SELECT CashPoint FROM  [dbo].MuCashShop_DATA AS T
    UPDATE [dbo].MuCashShop_data SET CashPoint = i.CashPoint
FROM (SELECT CashPoint FROM  [dbo].MEMB_INFO) i 
JOIN MuCashShop_DATA ON i.CashPoint = MuCashShop_DATA.CashPoint
   UPDATE [dbo].MEMB_INFO SET CashPoint = '0'
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

The issue: I want to run this every 5 minutes for example, I want to take `CashPoint` from `MEMB_INFO` and insert it into `MuCashShop_DATA.CashShop`

It runs ok, but the problem is that it does not + count it.

In `memb_info` cashpoint is added every hour (1 cashpoint), if I update `mucashshop_data` every one has 1 cashpoint... I need a query that does something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].MuCashShop_data 
SET CashPoint = CashPoint + i.CashPoint
```

Some help please? :(

Comment: What is the relationship of Memb_info and MuCashShop_data?  you are joining on CashPoint, but if you do that, you may as well just update to CashPoint * 2.

Comment: I cannot update to * 2, i need to store the actual amount of chashpoint in mucashshop_data + the new value of memb_info cashpoint...

Comment: You're missing my point.   What is the relationship of the two tables?

Comment: Well my game add every hour 1 gem to memb_info cashpoint. But in the actual SHOP the cashpoint are stored in mucashshop_data, so i wan to make the cashpoint usable somehow... both tables are stored in MuOnline.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you just answer your own question?

change this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].MuCashShop_data SET CashPoint = i.CashPoint
 FROM (SELECT CashPoint FROM  [dbo].MEMB_INFO) i 
 JOIN MuCashShop_DATA ON i.CashPoint = MuCashShop_DATA.CashPoint
```

to this:

```
UPDATE m SET m.CashPoint = m.CashPoint + i.CashPoint
  FROM MuCashShop_DATA m inner join
   (
          SELECT CashPoint FROM  [dbo].MEMB_INFO
     ) i 
         ON i.CashPoint = m.CashPoint
```

Comment: nope, that will add +1 to the current cashpoint. i want to add the cashpoint from memb_info to the current cashpoint amount from mucashshop_data. example: memb_info.cashpoint + mucashshop_data.cashpoint

Comment: I'm assuming that your data isn't as you expect, then.  Can you use sql fiddle to set up a scenario?  My guess is that you don't currently have cashpoint values in each table that match, since that is what you are joining on. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: My data is the same, so in memb_info cashpoint is int, in mucashshop_data cashpoint is int, i am trying to add memb_info.cashpoint to mucashshop_data.cashpoint. ADD = +

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you do this.

```
SELECT CashPoint FROM  [dbo].MuCashShop_DATA AS T

UPDATE A
SET    CashPoint = A.CashPoint + i.CashPoint
FROM   [dbo].MuCashShop_data A
       JOIN [dbo].MEMB_INFO i
         ON i.CashPoint = a.CashPoint

UPDATE [dbo].MEMB_INFO
SET    CashPoint = '0'
```

Comment: This is what happens: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "MuCashShop_DATA.CashPoint" could not be bound.

Comment: uhmm.. now it does not take anything. I must take the current value in memb_info.cashpoint lets say 10 and add to mucashshop_data.cashpoint. So i will call first table Cashpoint1(memb_info) and CashPoint2(mucashshop_data), so basicly i should do something like this: CashPoint1 + CashPoint2... get me?